# Debug Assertion Failed - C++

Tags: c++, debugging, assertion

I am trying to have a pointer in a struct point to an array of structs of another type. Here is my code:

```
struct Mesh 
{
    long masterRef;                 // The global fragment number
    long polygonCount;              // Number of polygons in the mesh
    long vertexCount;               // Number of verticies in the mesh
    Vertex *verti;                  // Pointer to verticies in the mesh
    Poly *poly;                     // Pointer to polygons in the mesh
    float center[3];                // The center of the mesh
    bool isVisible;                 // Is the mesh currently visible?
} typedef Mesh;

struct Region 
{
    bool hasPoly;
    long size1; 
    long size2;
    long size3;
    long size4;
    long size5;
    long size6;
    Mesh* meshptr; // the mesh with the polygons for this region
    long meshRef;
    std::vector<int> visvector;
    long regionsVisible;
};
```

As you can see, I am trying to create a mesh pointer in Region struct. The pointer will point to a Mesh in a mesh array. This line alone causes the program to crash with a debug assertion failed message and a "Expression: invalid null pointer"

Does anyone know what the problem could be? I would post the calling code but it crashes without it.

Comment: @James I have completely removed the calling code and it still crashes. Simply commenting out the line Mesh* meshprt; causes it to work fine again.

Comment: @Satchmo Brown - Given the message - `"Expression: invalid null pointer"`, check whether `meshptr` is pointing to any valid location using debugger at the pointer of crash. Also you are violating - **C++ Rule of Three**.

Comment: It cannot crash without the code :-) Could you please post the line which crashes (possibly with the needed context)?

Comment: @Vlad It has no calling line. I am serious. Maybe when the Region array is created but it crashes when that line is there and not when it isn't. There is no other code that involves meshptr anywhere. I promise.

Comment: If your code crashes without ever assigning the pointer then there's another issue in your program. At at best guess I think you may be assigning the address of a stack variable and trying to use it later, but we really need some code.

Comment: @James I just fixed it and if some guru could explain this please do. I move the Mesh* meshptr down to be the last element in the struct. And now it works. I'm puzzled to say the least.

Comment: Then it seems that there's other code that you may need to recompile when you change the layout of the struct. But without any code it's all just guesswork!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are "trying to have a pointer in a struct point to an array of structs".  To declare a pointer to an array, you need a slightly different syntax: `Mesh (*meshptr)[array_size];`.  As your structure stands now, `meshptr` is a pointer to a single `Mesh` object, not an array.  Attempting to use that pointer like an array will cause problems, as you will be directly accessing the memory following the pointer.  This might explain why moving the pointer to the end of the data structure seems to work.  When you do that, you are corrupting the memory following the structure instead of corrupting the structure members following the pointer.  Most likely, your code corrupted one of the last three fields of the structure and that corruption caused the error you are seeing.  Moving the pointer to the end might cause the error to stop, but it doesn't fix the problem (you are still corrupting memory, which can have any number of unexpected effects).

This is merely speculation based on stupid things that I have done in the past.  Without having more of your code, there's no way to tell for sure.